# Keep process running after JVM exits

Tags: java, process

I need to run a script after the jwm exits.  I have:

```
//run the script
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + script.getAbsolutePath());

System.exit(0);
```

The Script waits 5 seconds before continuing, but its killed whenever the jwm exits.  How can I prevent this?

Comment: @chresse I don't know the Windows way of handling the "process tree" but I believe this won't work; you'd need a Windows equivalent to Linux/Unix's `setsid()` for that to work; or use Windows services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. Answered my own question. "cmd /c start " did the trick.